Automatically add PATH to right files?
Every time I set up something new, I have to manually add it to my .zshrc file, otherwise I get "command not found" (I'm on macOS).
Is there any way to fix this?

Currently you are talking about two unrelated things (that might be off-topic too),  Can you [edit] your question, and share details of only 1 problem, and add more details?  (see: How to ask)

Short answer: No , there is no way to change .zshrc automagically.

It sounds like you're talking about binaries installed by npm specifically. You can either execute these with npx from the project directory, or install them globally (npm install --global) and then add ~/.node-modules/bin/ to your path. If this doesn't answer your question please give a detailed example of what you are trying to do.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
